# Windows Form Application-Can't Edit Source in C# Project and after deleting code there is no effect in Application.Why?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
//using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Notepad_X.Classes;
namespace Notepad_X
{
public partial class About : Form
{
    Main main;

    //Effect variables
    int currentGradientShift = 10;
    int gradiantStep = 5;
    Color c = new Color();

    public About()
    {
        main = Static.MainInstance;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void About_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      c = Color.FromArgb(76, 197, 82);
      if (Main.app_language.language.ToLower() != "english")
      {
          about_translator.Visible = true;
          about_translation.Visible = true;
          about_translator.Text = Main.app_language.Author;
      }
      else
      {
          about_translation.Visible = false;
          about_translator.Visible = false;
      }
      this.Text = Main.app_language[Strings.About];
      about_translation.Text = Main.app_language[Strings.Author];
      about_close.Text = Main.app_language[Strings.Close];
      about_dev.Text = Main.app_language[Strings.Developers];

      if (main.IconsCollection.Images.ContainsKey("about"))
      {
          Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(new         System.Drawing.Bitmap(main.IconsCollection.Images["about"]).GetHicon());
      }else{
          this.ShowIcon = false;
      }

      about_version.Text = Main.app_language[Strings.Version] + " " + Main.VersionName;     
    }

    private void effect_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random g = new Random();
        effect.Interval =(int)(10 * (0.5+g.NextDouble()));
        Graphics grfx  = CreateGraphics();
        Font font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 35, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        String strText="Notepad X";
        SizeF sizfText = new SizeF(grfx.MeasureString(strText,font));
        PointF ptfTextStart = new PointF(5,5);
        PointF ptfGradientStart = new PointF(0,0);
        PointF ptfGradientEnd = new PointF((float)(currentGradientShift),100);
        LinearGradientBrush grBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(ptfGradientStart,ptfGradientEnd,c ,Color.WhiteSmoke);
        grfx.DrawString(strText, font, grBrush, ptfTextStart);

        grfx.Dispose();

        currentGradientShift += gradiantStep;
        if(currentGradientShift == 200) 
        {
            gradiantStep = -5;
        }else if(currentGradientShift == -50){
            gradiantStep = 5;
        }
    }

    private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void about_website_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://notepad-x.sourceforge.net");
        }catch (Exception)
        {}

    }

    private void about_nohponex_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://notepad-x.sourceforge.net/?author=1");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {}

    }

    private void about_licence_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {}
    }

    private void about_donate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://sourceforge.net/project/project_donations.php?group_id=202614");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {}
    }
}
```

}

This is a Windows Form Application in C#.This is "about" box of open source text editor named "NOTEPADX". I want to edit it's components but there is no effect on program after changing code or changing by drag and drop.it always give the default window as it was before. I want to know what is the problem. Why i am not able to change the code .

Comment: Do you rebuild the project? Try rebuild all, if there are errors try to resolve them.

Comment: i rebuild it and one another solution copy whole project and then rebuild again but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have errors in your code. When it happens, Visual Studio has this pesky feature which propose you to run the last working version. If you say yes, it will always do the same...

In Visual Studio try go to Tools > Settings > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run and check that the secon drop down list (something like "in case of build error") is set to "do not run" instead of "run the previous version".

My VS is not in English, so the names may not be exactly these ones.

Comment: it gives me one error while compiling "app.congig is moved or does not exist".so i create a app.config for it.now that error did not appear again

Comment: Thanks It Works.i want to ask that if resharper can help me in development.while i modifying the code it gets errors.

Comment: Sorry I've never used resharper, so I can't help you. If you have questions about it, you should post another question as it is a different subject.